# Synthesis of 3-Methylenecyclopentene from 1-methylCyclobutene

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

How do I make 3-Methylenecyclopentene

[image]

from 1-methylcyclobutene?

[image]

I thought to do ring opening reaction to add 1 carbon atoms but this won't add double bond in product. How to start please?

Comment: What sort of ring opening?

Comment: Here's a thought: 1) Simmon-Smith reaction, 2) bromine addition, 3) double dehydrobromination

Comment: I don't know  Simon-smith reaction. Can ring opening epoxide reaction work?

Answer (score 4):

Here is my try.

1. Ozonolysis
2. Aldol condensation using a hindered base (like LDA)
3. Wittig reagent to convert $\ce{C=O}$ to $\ce{C=C}$

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**

I used $\ce{LDA}$ which abstracts a proton from the least hindered carbon near to a carbonyl group. (So that the resulting carbanion is stable).
I am not drawing the enolate ion formation etc. You can find the reaction mechanism for aldol condensation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldol_condensation) and the reaction using $\ce{LDA}$ [here](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/08/05/reagent-friday-lithium-di-isopropyl-amide-lda/).
[image]

[image]

After protonation, you can heat the compound to remove $\ce{OH-}$ which is a simple dehydation. There are two possible alkenes. One of them (the one given below) is more stable because of conjugation.

[image]

**Step 3:**

We are almost done. To replace $\ce{C=O}$ with $\ce{C=C}$, use [wittig reagent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wittig_reaction).

[image]

Comment: You'll need low temp for your intramolecualr aldol but otherwise, this is sold.

Comment: What are the chances of conjugate addition with a Wittig anion? Would Tebbe or Petasis be more likely to succeed? Well, if those things would be an issue, there's a ton of methylenation reactions.